# subclass inheriting annotations from parent class for a function

Tags: python, mypy

```
class A:
    def test(self, value: int, *args: str, **kwargs: int) -> str:
        pass 


class B(A)
    def test(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff
        super().test(value)
```

Is there a way to tell mypy that the subclass's `test` has identical typing as the parent class?

I ask this because some the typing of some methods I'm inheriting require a lot of imports. One example would be `requests.Session.get`. If I'm just writing a wrapper that manipulates the headers before sending everything to the proper function, how can I tell mypy to just consider the annotations of the parent class for a specific function?

Comment: Put `B.test` under an `if not typing.TYPE_CHECKING` block

Comment: Does the code in "do some stuff" actually make use of any of the arguments?

Comment: @blhsing yes, it uses most of them (though not all). The point is that I'd like test to be transparent to to the IDE, so that it shows the same annotations as the underlying function.

Comment: This is actually a wanted feature, with priority 1. Here's the [relevant issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3903) (and TL;DR - no, you can't).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @SUTerliakov in the comments, there is currently no directly supported way to annotate a child method with the same annotations as the overridden method of the parent class.

However, with the introduction of [typing.ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) in Python 3.10, a viable workaround would be to define a wrapper function that uses the parameter specifications of the parent function object to annotate an inner wrapper function that actually calls the parent function after doing "some stuff" with the arguments, and returns the inner wrapper function to make it an actual method of the child class:

```
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec
from collections.abc import Callable

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

class A:
    def test(self, value: int, *args: str, **kwargs: int) -> str:
        print('base method with:', self, value, args, kwargs)
        return ' '.join(map(str, (value, args, kwargs)))
    
class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def inherit(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            print('do something in wrapper with:', args, kwargs)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    test = inherit(A.test)

print(B().test(1, 'foo', 'bar', a=2))
```

Demo of the code passing mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=828b3ba31c5c4979ff46ae2b2213dbc4

Demo of the code running on repl.it: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ThriftyZealousCustomer

Demo of type hints in PyCharm:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to define `B.test` under an `if not typing.TYPE_CHECKING` block, it's easy enough to make a no-op decorator factory to take over any signature you need:

```py
import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t


P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R = t.TypeVar("R")


def withSignatureFrom(
    f: cx.Callable[P, R]
) -> cx.Callable[[cx.Callable[..., object]], cx.Callable[P, R]]:
    return lambda _: _  # type: ignore[return-value]


class A:
    def test(self, value: int, *args: str, **kwargs: int) -> str:
        return ""


class B(A):
    @withSignatureFrom(A.test)
    def test(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff
        return super().test(value)
```

```py
>>> B().test("")  # mypy: Argument 1 to "test" of "B" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" [arg-type]
```

This only handles instance methods though - you'll need to define other `@typing.overload`s  for `@withSignatureFrom` if you want to handle `@staticmethod`s and `@classmethod`s.

---

If you're running `mypy` in `--strict` mode, you'll have to also decide what to do with untyped definitions; e.g. by setting the configuration `disallow_untyped_defs = False`.